# Python (Ubuntu) installing python-dev on none default version of python

Tags: python-2.7

I currently have python 2.6 (default) installed on my VPS (Plesk). I have also installed python 2.7 which is the version I want to use 99% of the time. I need to install python-dev on python 2.7 but running

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

installs under python 2.6

How do I install python-dev for python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Just try `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`.
Before doing this, don't miss to get your apt repository fresh! `sudo apt-get update`

If you're going to use different python envrionment, I strongly recommend you to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks,that worked. On a more general note and the main source of my problem how do I install packages on a none default version of Python. i.e sudo apt-get install MySQLdb-python installs under 2.6 how do I force it to install under python2.7?

Comment: That's why I recommend you to use virtualenv. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) is very useful to you. ;)